# Grip control in Kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I want to use the grip control in Kinect. I cant find sources related to grip control in Kinect sdk.

Does Kinect sdk provides inbuilt support for recognizing the grip movement,or we have to write our own?

Is there any open source samples available for grip control in Kinect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kinect for Windows SDK v1.7 introduced Grip recognition for up to four hands simultaneously, which includes new controls for WPF.

I suggest you download that version of the SDK in case you are not using it yet, and check the documentation for details of its usage and capabilities.

[Source: kinectingforwindows.com](http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/2013/03/18/introducting-kinect-for-windows-sdk-v1-7/)
[Source: blog.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/03/18/the-latest-kinect-for-windows-sdk-is-here.aspx)

Comment: Thanks John! I got it,i found the sample code in the samples provided by Kinect SDK 1.7.

Comment: @Naren can you please share sample code on how to use the grip and fire an event based on if the grip is detected or released? I have seen the sample WPF Basic Controls but I am unable to understand how SDK uses it.

Comment: @Faizan  Sorry for the late reply .If you like to use grip control you have create a KinectRegion in WPF. If you want to detect the hand grip without KinectRegion  please refer this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e068b08-a407-446b-8b03-737ab6d033bd/how-to-handle-handpointergrip-with-kinect-control?forum=kinectsdk)

Comment: @Naren Thanks for the response! I'll check out the links and let you know. I basically want to control Google Earth via Kinect gestures. What would you prefer? If I use the KinectRegion in WPF, I don't know how would I integrate Google Earth in KinectRegion, since I have added GE in WPF as a webbrowser component. Do you have any suggestions if I am going on the right track? I am a beginner in C# and Kinect SDK. Currently using SDK1.8. I would appreciate if you can share tutorials or links from where I should start to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Faizan As far as I know , for using grip control you need to use the KinectRegion. Once I tried to use grip control in webbrowser but there is no direct solution to control the webpage components. I translated the mouse coordinates obtained from grip control to move the mouse pointer. It was not perfect and I could not find a way to simulate click events in webbrowser. I worked using Kinect sdk 1.7 and I even doubt whether v1.8 supports this kind of feature.